# Laravel Route with Multiple Parameters - How to get correct database result

Tags: laravel, routes

I am a couple of weeks in to learning Laravel and have come across a problem which I can not find the answer to by myself, or online.

I am building a directory website with urls structured like:

1. directory.co.uk/parks
2. directory.co.uk/parks/{county-name}
3. directory.co.uk/parks/{county-name}/{park-name}

As {park-name} is not unique, I am struggling to return the page for an individual park. The controller needs to look up the `county`.`id` using the `county`.`slug` and *then* the `park`.`id` using the `park`.`county_id` and the  `park`.`slug`.

I have routes in the web.php file such as:

```
Route::get('/parks','ParksController@index')->name('parks');
Route::get('/parks/{county}/{park}','ParksController@show')->name('park');
```

I have Parks and Counties models and (belongsTo and hasMany relationships set up between the two).

I have this is in both models:

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'seo_url';
    }
```

Then in my ParksController, I am at a loss. I currently have:

```
public function show(Counties $county, Parks $park)
    {
        //return $park;
        //dd($park);
        return view('parks.park', ['park'=>$park]);
    }
```

I have also tried the non-Eloquent way:

```
public function show($county_slug,$park_slug)
    {
        $county = DB::table('counties')->where('seo_url',$county_slug)->get();

        $county_id = $county->pluck('id');

        $park = DB::table('parks')->where('county_id', $county_id)->where('seo_url', $park_slug)->get();

        //dd($county_id);
        //return $park;
        return view('parks.park', ['park'=>$park]);
    }
```

This returns a 404 error. Any help would be much appreciated. (I have done a lot of reading on Route model binding, but can not see any examples like mine.)

Comment: What is the actual route (URL) that you're navigating to that causes the 404 error?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has an undocumented feature in its [explicit model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#explicit-binding), where the callback can be given the current Route the binding is for. This can allow you to access the other parameters and use them to add conditionals.

```php
Router::bind('park', static function ($value, Route $route) {
    $query = Parks::where('seo_url', '=', $value);

    if ($route->hasParameter('county')) {
        $county = $route->parameter('county');

        $query->where('county_id', '=', $county instanceof Counties ? $county->id : $county);
    }

    return $query->first() ?? abort(404);
});
```